# Problem with insert text to User Control TextBox

Tags: c#

I made user control called "UC_addressForm" where is TextBox called "UC_addr_company"
This User Control i placed inside Form1. My code inside User control it look like this:

```
public partial class UC_addressForm : UserControl
{
    public string company
    {
        get { return UC_addr_company.Text; }
        set { UC_addr_company.Text = value; }
    }

    public UC_addressForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

}
```

But when i try insert text into uc textbox via:

```
UC_addressForm af = new UC_addressForm();
af.company = "ooo";
```

in Form1_Load event
this unfortunately does not work, its means textbox after compile is empty.
I have no idea why...

Comment: Have you try to recreate the project, the control and the form from nothing ?

Comment: i started new empty project and created usercontrol with one textbox and rebulid solution but still not working. I use netFramewor 4.7.2

Comment: Oops. Did not see that. Did you add the control into the form using the `this.Controls.Add(af)` ? Don't forget to set `Location` for example.

Comment: No, i dragAndDrop uc from toolbox. When i placed uc using controls.add then it works fine but how do this without dynamically uc add

Comment: ok problem was in i created new instance of uc. I must use instance which is form desinger. Now works great !

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this:

```
UC_addressForm af = new UC_addressForm();
```

And use the instance name provider by the visual form designer of VS instead of af.